# How do I find out more information about a pending software update?

Tags: software-update

On my MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) with macOS 10.15.4 (19E287), I am shown a software update that I cannot seem to install and that I want to know more about.

How can I find out more information about such a pending software update and eventually install it?

Here is a GIF animation for further context: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqFA4.jpg

Comment: try `softwareupdate -l` in termal first to see what comes up

Comment: It's saying that no new software is available.

Comment: Could you try `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.plist` Also have you recently updated you OS / when and how did the issue first start? And can you paste the result?

Comment: This is giving me `{
    LatestMajorOSSeenByUserBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.InstallAssistant.Catalina";
    ProductKeysLastSeenByUser =     (
        "061-90745"
    );
}` and yes indeed, I recently upgraded to Catalina!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided result, the Security update "061-90745" is an update still trying to be installed for [Mojave](https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15customerseed-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz)!

[image: code example from apple security update]

Clear the old update with `defaults delete com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate LatestMajorOSSeenByUserBundleIdentifier && softwareupdate --list`

It removes the old incompatible string then refreshes the list from Apple

Congrats on the move to Catalina!

Comment: Thanks! But inside `/Library/Updates` I only have `index.plist` and `ProductMetadata.plist`. No such folder.

Comment: Just updated the answer with a command to delete the string directly from the software update pending list. Let me know if that works!